# swagger aggregation with spring cloud gateway and consul

Tags: swagger, openapi, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway microservice with more than 50 microservices that are routed with it. I need to aggregate the swagger for all these microservices in gateway swagger.

for this goal i add springdoc dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and add configuration:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    displayOperationId: true
    oauth:
      clientId: lc-client-test
      clientSecret: c327e9ea-e4cc-49b2-a0f7-f27d081c268c
    urls:
  api-docs:
    path: /swagger/${spring.application.name}/api-docs
    resolve-schema-properties: true
```

But this doesnt show me aggregated swagger. What more do I need to do?

**I use spring-boot 3.1.1 with cloud dependency 2022.0.3**

thanks